# How to use DynamoDB with CakePHP 3.x

Tags: cakephp, amazon-dynamodb, cakephp-3.0

I have just started an application with CakePHP 3.x and Amazon DynamoDB.
As I know, CakePHP doesn't have built-in support for DynamoDB (NoSQL).

So, how can I use DynamoDB with CakePHP 3.x?

If there is not a plugin/library that does this work, someone please guide me which CakePHP classes I must customize to make it works.

Thank you.

Comment: Can't you use the plain AWS SDK PHP in CakePHP? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/service-dynamodb.html

Comment: Thanks you, @notionquest.
 If use the plain AWS SDK PHP, I can not utilise CakePHP Model Layer and some components such as Auth won't work. Right?